# Redis lexicographical ordering doesn't work

Tags: redis

I'm trying to create a basic autocomplete feature (I created those below manually to test it out first), but somehow I don't get the result I want after adding some keys.

I add every possible version of a word and keep the exact words with * to mark them (For example, if 10 keys are returned and 3 of them have asterisk, they'll be shown as suggestions), so I can query my hash database after that and get hash results.

There are a few duplicate entry attempts, but since it returns integer 0 for them, I presumed that they weren't added for the second time.

I use Redis 3.0.6

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 ba
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 bar
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 bar*
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 f
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 foo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 foo*
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 foob
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fooba
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 foobar
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 foobar*
(integer) 1
```

No problem so far.
I want all words that start with `fo`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank zset fo
(integer) 5
```

It gives five, so I increment by one (like shown [here](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) if I get it right) and query all keys.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange zset 6 -1
1) "foo"
2) "foo*"
3) "foob"
4) "fooba"
5) "foobar"
6) "foobar*"
```

No problem, I get the desired result.

I keep adding keys.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 b
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 c
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fi
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fil
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 filli
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fillib
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 fillibo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 filliboy
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 filliboya
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank zset fo
(integer) 14
```

I do another search.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange zset 15 -1
1) "foo"
2) "foo*"
3) "foob"
4) "fooba"
5) "foobar"
6) "foobar*"
```

Ok again. I keep adding.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 d
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 e
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 x
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 y
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 z
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 filli*
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 0 filliboya*
(integer) 1
```

This is the part where things get interesting. I want to get all the words that start with `filli`, but I can't. Why?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrank zset filli
(integer) 11
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange zset 12 -1
 1) "filli*"
 2) "fillib"
 3) "fillibo"
 4) "filliboy"
 5) "filliboya"
 6) "filliboya*"
 7) "fo"
 8) "foo"
 9) "foo*"
10) "foob"
11) "fooba"
12) "foobar"
13) "foobar*"
14) "x"
15) "y"
16) "z"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: What is your expected/required output?

Comment: @Amit , I'm trying to get all records that start with a given word. In the last example, `filli` must return only `filli, fillib, fillibo, filliboy, filliboya, filliboya*`, but it returns 16 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexicographical ordering is working, but you're asking for the entire range from the member you've retrieved to the end (-1). Since Redis v2.8 you should be using the [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) command for that purpose. In your case, it should be as follows:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX zset [filli [filli\xff
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but while this returns `filli` and `filli*`, `ZRANGEBYLEX zset [fi [fi\xff` only returns `fi` while I need every word that start with fi. What could be the reason for that? Does escaping only appies when we're dealing with cli?

Comment: The '\xff' notation for specifying bytes by their hexadecimal value is supported by the cli. Depending on your client/programming language, you may need to prepare the query differently. What are you using?

Comment: Node.js. Right now I started experimenting with cli to learn the basics but I am planning to use the following node package in production. https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis